# recognize which UIImageView has been tapped and get its index in an array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So right now I have code that makes a TapGestureRecognizer for each image in an array, and what I'm trying to do is return the index of the image that has been tapped by the user. What would be the easiest way to achieve this? I'm new to Swift so I got part of this from a youtube tutorial and I don't really understand how to use gesture recognizers :/

This is what I have so far (simplified to only include what is relevant):

```
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

var recognizersAdded = false
@IBOutlet weak var right1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var right2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var right3: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var houseImages = [self.right1, self.right2, self.right3]

    for imageview in houseImages
    {
         if !recognizersAdded
         {
            let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped))
            imageview!.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
            imageview!.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
         }


       }
            recognizersAdded = true
    }
@IBAction func imageTapped(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
   if let view = recognizer.view as? UIImageView
   {
        var i = 0
        //set i to index of image tapped
        advance4(index: i)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have an array storing all your images, it's fairly easy to know what image (and index) has been tapped by searching the image index within `houseImages`.

Because you don't need complex verifications to get your index with `firstIndex(where: [...])`, I would suggest to simply use `firstIndex(of: UIImageView)` in your case.

```
@IBAction func imageTapped(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let tappedView = recognizer.view as? UIImageView else {
        return
    }
    let index = self.houseImages.firstIndex(of: tappedView)
    print("House image index = \(index)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily since you are already creating an array of `UIImageView`'s and you just need the index of the tapped imageView within the array, you simply need to use the method `firstIndex(where:`, here is the code:

```swift
@IBAction func imageTapped(recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let houseImages = [self.right1, self.right2, self.right3]
    if let view = recognizer.view as? UIImageView {
        let indexOfSelectedImageView = houseImages.firstIndex(where: { $0 == view })
        print(indexOfSelectedImageView)
    }
}
```